# How often should a transient service should be resolved inside a singleton hosted service?

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my asp.net app, there is a hosted background service that processes data as it comes and writes them to the database. Writing to the database is done by a transient `AppDbContext` class. From what I read, the context should be created for each time new data is being processed but that can happen potentially hundreds of times per second. Here is that code.

```cs
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken ct)
{
    await foreach (var data in _dataChannelService.ReadAllAsync(ct))
    {
        await using var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateAsyncScope();
        var appDb = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<AppDbContext>();

        // Processing...

        await appDb.AddAsync(data, ct);
        await appDb.SaveChangesAsync(ct);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, I could create the context once and use it all the time but it is against the transient nature of the `AppDbContext` class. Here is what that would look like.

```cs
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken ct)
{
    await using var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateAsyncScope();
    var appDb = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<AppDbContext>();

    await foreach (var data in _dataChannelService.ReadAllAsync(ct))
    {
        // Processing...

        await appDb.AddAsync(data, ct);
        await appDb.SaveChangesAsync(ct);
    }
}
```

I do not want to resolve an `AppDbContext` instance in every iteration but resolving it only once does not feel natural either. Is there a middle ground?

Comment: @PoulBak this is the recommended pattern for creating background services in asp.net Here is docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: Upon second thought, you don't run in parallel, so it should be fine. I would move `await appDb.SaveChangesAsync(ct);` outside the loop.